# Is it possible to activate the subtitles for the cinematics?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is the captioning present for Diablo III cinematics, both for the in-game non-interactive events and the full-fledged movies at the beginning of the Acts? If so, how can I activate them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They both are in the **Sound** section of the **Options** menu.